# NServiceBus Message Handlers not firing in expected order Saga handler fires early

Tags: nservicebus

We are using our own host and want to specify a single handler to fire first. We have a message validation handler that we would like to fire before our Saga handler. We have tried to set the order using the code below but looking in our logs our saga message handler fires first then the validation handler fires. Were stumped and wondered if the saga has anything to do with it? 
If you have any ideas please let us know.

Documentation from here: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/handlers/handler-ordering

```
NServiceBus.Configure.With()
 ...
 .UnicastBus()
      .LoadMessageHandlers<First<YourHandler>>()
```

Our code looks like this:

```
var bus =  Configure.With()
    ...
    .UnicastBus()
          .LoadMessageHandlers(new First<ValidationHandler>())
```

Comment: Just curious (not that I think this should be required) does it work if you specify the .AndThen<SagaMessageHandler>() ?

Comment: Yes, we have just discovered that it does work if .AndThen<SagaMessageHandler<()

Comment: Unfortunately it would mean a lot of extra work in our automated deployment code to implement this. btw we are using NSB V2.5

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the example in the NServiceBus faq. I had the same problem, i was also doing

```
.UnicastBus()
      .LoadMessageHandlers(new First<ValidationHandler>())
```

When I switched to

```
.UnicastBus()
      .LoadMessageHandlers<First<YourHandler>>()
```

it ran the handlers in the expected order